# How to create subset of object, rename some keys and then restructure it?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I would like to take an existing object and create a new one that only has the key/value pairs I require, rename some keys and restructure in a specific format.

#### Original object

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "start": "2016-02-29",
  "end": "2099-12-31",
  "code": "10000",
  "type": "Filtered",
  "dvalue": "287.96",
  "benchmark": "131"
}
...etc.
```

#### New object

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "data": {
    "x": "287.96",
    "y": "131"
  }
}
...etc.
```

I explored lodash, and got close with creating a subset and then renaming the keys but I need help to nest `x` and `y` into a new key called `data`.

#### My code:

```
var newItems = _.map(items, _.partialRight(_.pick, ['id', 'dvalue', 'benchmark']));

Object.keys(newItems).forEach(function (key) {
    newItems[key].x = newItems[key].dvalue;
    newItems[key].y = newItems[key].benchmark;
    delete newItems[key].dvalue;
    delete newItems[key].benchmark;
});
```

#### Returns:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "x": "287.96",
  "y": "131"
}
...etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use-case, I'm not sure you really need something like lodash. You should be able to do this with the built in `Array.prototype.map`.

Additionally, [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) can make the code cleaner:

```js
const newItems = items.map(({id, dvalue, benchmark}) => ({
  id,
  x: dValue,
  y: benchmark  
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the property directly and rename the other nested properties.

```js
var data = [{ id: "123", start: "2016-02-29", end: "2099-12-31", code: "10000", type: "Filtered", dvalue: "287.96", benchmark: "131" }],
    result = data.map(({ id, dvalue: x, benchmark: y }) => ({ id, data: { x, y } }));

console.log(result);
```